# How to change opacity on children

Tags: html, css

Can I show a low color on a `div` so that the image would be clearer like on the first image?

I covered the image with a `div` that has opacity so that `div` will be shown while the image is showing.

Please tell me if there is a way without using opacity.

This is what I want as result:

[image]

How can I define the opacity to not affect the children elements? Here is what I want it to be:

I tried `color: rgb(255, 255, 255);` but it shows me the same result.

Here is what it is right now, it does not change the opacity on children.

[image]

**my CSS**

```
.image-cover{ 
  background:#858C94;
  opacity:0.7;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: -66.8px;
  position: relative;
}
.mediv{
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

**my HTML**

```
<div class='row image-cover'>
  <div className='mediv'>2</div>
  <div className='mediv' >bk52</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: What do you mean by "show a low color on a `<div>`"?

Comment: i got my answer at `@TusharMaheshwari`'s answer thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Alpha while declaring Background property of parent as

background:rgba(133,140,148,0.5)

instead of opacity. so child elements will not be affected.

Comment: That's not aspect ratio. That's Alpha - A channel dealing with per-pixel transparency.